# URL rewrite in ASP.net for multi language

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, multilingual

With the example URL:

```
www.domain.com/contact-us
```

Which renders in `English`.  There are a set of other languages this website supports:

```
www.domain.com/es/contact-us
www.domain.com/jp/contact-us  
www.domain.com/de/contact-us
www.domain.com/pt/contact-us
```

Here is the re-write rule for English (default language)

```
<rewrite url="^/contact-us(\?(.+))?$" to="~/Pages/Contact.aspx$1" processing="stop"/>
```

How would I modify this/add a new rule to re-write:

```
www.domain.com/jp/contact-us
```

To:

```
~/Pages/Contact.aspx?language=jp
```

Preferably without having to write a new rule, for every language for every content page!

To complicate things, it needs to match IETF language tags.  These are varied enough that it looks like a regex to match them would be a difficult route:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag

Ideally I need to get the list of languages from the database, and match the language tag field on the fly.  But I'm not sure how to do this as I've only ever written static rules.

Comment: Since you need to connect to a database, couldn't you write your own HTTP module (based on the HttpContext.RewritePath method)?

Comment: @SimonMourier any good tutorials you can link me to showing me how to do this?  I've had a look but find it all a bit confusing!

Comment: @SimonMourier I've actually gotten a module to work up to the stage where when you give it the url `/de/contact-us` it gives `/contact-us?lang=de` but `RewritePath` needs a physical path which means it looks like I should write all my url rewrite rules in this module?

Comment: @SimonMourier sorry for all the comments, but is this: http://pastebin.com/HntCsbdF along the right lines?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the idea. Few comments: for robustness, you want to test it in various environment (iis, iisexpress? with standard apps and lots of custom modules loaded, like MVC, see if your code doesn't mess up with other extensions, etc.). Also the check for static files is a bit naïve :-), but maybe sufficient for your context. Note: you can use Server.MapPath to get physical paths from urls.

Comment: @SimonMourier I'm currently using Inteligencia URL rewrite which makes writing the majority of my rules easy.  Is there any way to achieve what I want without having to write every rule in my own custom module?  I'll do it if I have to but would rather use the Inteligencia URL rewriting for the bulk of this.

Comment: On the processing event, if you don't rewrite the path, then the next module in chain will be able to catch it and process it

Comment: Can't you redirect it to a Dispatcher and from there process the langauge as parameter?

Comment: from  `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath`you get a String you can parse with simple regex looking for `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to a `.htaccess` file in your home directory? If so, you can make an automatic rewrite rule by writing the following

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /(.*)/contact-us/ /Pages/Contact.aspx?language=$1
RewriteRule /contact-us/ /Pages/Contact.aspx?language=en
```

Let me explain:

After `RewriteRule`, the user-friendly URL is on the left, here `/(.*)/contact-us/` where `(.*)` is where `jp` will take place. 
Then that `jp` is transposed on the real URL on the right, here `/Pages/Contact.aspx?language=$1` to replace `$1`.

Input URL: `http://www.example.com/jp/contact-us` 
Output URL: `http://www.example.com/Pages/Contact.aspx?language=jp`

For the second `RewriteRule`, as the URL `http://www.example.com/contact-us/` does not match the first model, it will turn into `http://www.example.com/Pages/Contact.aspx?language=en` automatically.

Please remember that the `.htaccess` file **MUST** be in the root directory (alongside `Pages` folder).  Otherwise you will not get the desired result.

Comment: Giving you the bounty, I think having two rules `/contact-us/ /Pages/Contact.aspx?language=en` and `/(.*)/contact-us/ /Pages/Contact.aspx?language=$1` is a clever solution

Comment: You can also do `/(.*)/(.*)/ /Pages/$2.aspx?language=$1` to programmatically bind new pages.

Answer (score 3):

Solved this by writing my own URL rewrite module.  Sample code for anyone who runs into similar problems is below.  Decided to dump all other URL rewriting and route everything through this module instead.

Don't think this is easily possible with static rules.

```
public class DynamicURLRewrite : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.AuthorizeRequest += new EventHandler(context_AuthorizeRequest);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void context_AuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rw = new Rewriter();
        rw.Process();
    }
}

public class Rewriter
{
    public void Process()
    {
        using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Rewriter process"))
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Current;

            var rawURL = context.Request.RawUrl;
            var querystring = String.Empty;
            var urlParts = rawURL.Split('?');
            var url = urlParts[0];
            if (urlParts.Count() == 2) querystring = urlParts[1];
            if (url.StartsWith("/")) url = url.Substring(1);

            // Get language component
            Translation.Language inLanguage = null;
            {
                foreach (var lang in Translation.Language.GetAllLanguages())
                {
                    if (url.StartsWith(lang.LanguageTag, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        inLanguage = lang;
                        url = url.Substring(lang.LanguageTag.Length);
                        if (url.StartsWith("/")) url = url.Substring(1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (inLanguage == null)
                {
                    inLanguage =
                        Translation.Language.GetLanguage(
                            Settings.Translation.ProjectReferenceVersionRequiredLanguageTag);
                }
            }

            // Querystring
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(querystring)) querystring += "&";
                querystring += "lang=" + inLanguage.LanguageTag.ToLower();
                querystring = "?" + querystring;
            }

            // Root pages
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
                {
                    context.RewritePath("~/pages/default.aspx" + querystring);
                    return;
                }
                if (url.Equals("login"))
                {
                    context.RewritePath("~/pages/login.aspx" + querystring);
                    return;
                }
```

And then some more complex rules:

```
            // Handlers
            if (url.StartsWith("handlers/"))
            {
                // Translation serving
                if(url.StartsWith("handlers/translations/"))
                {
                    var regex = new Regex("handlers/translations/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+).json", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    var match = regex.Match(url);
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        context.RewritePath("~/handlers/translation/getprojecttranslation.ashx" + querystring + "&project=" + match.Groups[1] + "&language=" + match.Groups[2]);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
```